# Script to download latest versions of software and drivers

Tags: windows, script

I would like to have a script of some sort that can download a stack of software for me,
for example

// run script, downloads into current directory

- download latest graphics drivers
- download notepad ++, foobar, skype, ...

I would then run it every time I reformat.

It would be nice if I could silent-install everything too, ala boot-camp

Comment: Please [edit] your question (so its a question) with more details explaining what you have tried and what you are working with. More information helps us help you.

Comment: Script in which language? However you can use Allmyapps.com for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Ninite](http://www.ninite.com) or [AllMyApps](http://www.allmyapps.com) for this functionality. It won't be a script, but you can look at the link URL for the download and save the address. Don't save the actual file, as they are set to expire